# InsertOnSubmit - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have 2 models.

AccountEntity

```cs
[Table(Name = "Account")]
    public class AccountEntity
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false, Name = "email")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false, Name = "pwd")]
        public string pwd { get; set; }
        [Column(CanBeNull = false, Name = "row_guid")]
        public Guid guid { get; set; }

        private EntitySet<DetailsEntity> details_id { get; set; }
        [Association(Storage = "details_id", OtherKey = "id", ThisKey = "id")]
        public ICollection<DetailsEntity> detailsCollection { get; set; }
    }
```

DetailsEntity

```cs
[Table(Name = "Details")]

    public class DetailsEntity
    {
    public DetailsEntity(AccountEntity a) {
        this.Account = a;
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "int")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    private EntityRef<AccountEntity> _account = new EntityRef<AccountEntity>();
    [Association(IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_account", ThisKey = "id")]
    public AccountEntity Account { get; set; }
}
```

Main

```cs
 using (Database db = new Database())
 {
     AccountEntity a = new AccountEntity();
     a.email = "hahaha";
     a.pwd = "13212312";
     a.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
     db.Account.InsertOnSubmit(a);
     db.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

that has relationship `AccountEntity <- DetailsEntity (1-n)`

when I'm trying to insert a record an exception is thrown (`NullReferenceException`)

cause: by `EntitySet` null

please help me make insert it.

---

I have found problem at

```
private EntitySet<DetailsEntity> details_id { get; set; } // this is properties
```

this must be new instance if has no ref

```
private EntitySet<DetailsEntity> details_id = new EntitySet<DetailsEntity>();
```

Comment: Is this entity framework code first?

Comment: It seems to be linq to sql (submitchanges is function of linq to sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Details table with the following

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
```

As you need to generate the Primary key on inertion of data into it.

Hope this will help.